# Laravel slice collection after an element

Tags: php, laravel, collections, slice

So I have this Model, which am going to name Clients
Clients has

1. id int PK
2. name varchar
3. phone int
4. city varchar
5. active tinyint

I chose this way to get the phone numbers grouped by cities

```
return Clients::select('name','phone','city')->selectSub('lpad(phone,1,'0'))->where('active',1)->groupBy('city')->paginate(10);
```

I want to slice the collection to a sub collection from a certain client, in other terms, if I have the following output :

1. John 0123456 Paris
2. Jake 0255664 Montreal
3. Jane 0165656 London
4. Fred 0164465 Toronto
5. Joan 0556494 Barcelona
6. Pete 0656897 Roma

How can I proceed to slice this collection so as to get the 2 last items (4 last items, 6 items ... in other terms from an entry I select)
I know Laravel has a slice method for collections, but how to do that dynamically ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$records = Clients::select('name','phone','city')->selectSub('lpad(phone,1,'0'))->where('active',1)->groupBy('city')->paginate(10);
```

Assuming $name = "Jane"

```
$value = collect($records)->filter(function($value) use ($name) {
    return $value->name === $name;
})->keys()->first();
```

Here $value will hold the index of Jane.

Now you can achieve the slicing by

```
$records = collect($records)->slice($value, 2)->all();
```

But there is one side effect, if the name isn't found, you will get $value as null. Check whether $value is null or not before processing slicing.

Comment: I know that, but what I'm trying to achieve is have like an argument from which the collection gets sliced. Laravel's collection slice uses a global index, `$mycollection->slice(3)` will slice from the fourth one, I want a way to get the index of an item in a collection

Comment: Couldn't get you. Can you brief bit more?

Comment: So considering the output mentionned in the post, let's say I want to get all the entries following "Jane", how can I do that. And so on for all the other "Clients", I enter a name, a function gets its index and gets the following entries.

Comment: You could use splice for that. With the index you have, run splice on the collections. Like collect($records)->splice($value);