# Laravel: Order by after slice object

Tags: sql, laravel

Actually I have a slice on the object:

`$projects = Project::slice($offset, $limit)->get()`

I want to order by field 'order' and use ordering 'asc', think should look like this, but not this is wrong.

`$projects = Project::slice($offset, $limit)->orderBy('order','asc')->get();`

Which is the correct way to make it works?

Comment: Is `Project` an Eloquent model?

Comment: Possible duplicate / could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664610/laravel-slice-collection-after-an-element

Comment: Yes, it is. @RossWilson

Comment: is it erroring? If so, what is the error/returned response

Comment: Any error, i get the data but not ordered. @mbozwood

Answer (score 0):

Method `slice()` is applied to collections, and method `orderBy()` is applied to construct queries.

Change the line to the following:

`$projects = Project::orderBy('order','asc')->slice($offset, $limit)->get();`